# absolute path not working but relative path working

Tags: php, apache, filepath

I have two files `test.php` and `test1.php` on this path `http://172.16.15.11/appointment/src/`

I am checking for file `test1.php` whether its exist or not but it does not work when i am giving `absolute path` :

i have the below code in `test.php`

```
//giving absolute path not working
var_dump(file_exists('http://172.16.15.11/appointment/src/test1.php')); //return false

//but when i give relative path it does work
var_dump(file_exists('test1.php')); //return true
```

To cross check this i tried `include` in my `test.php`

```
include('http://172.16.15.11/appointment/src/test1.php'); //but in this case absolute path work
```

If i am giving absolute path its works when i

```
1. include('http://172.16.15.11/appointment/src/test1.php'); 

2. header('location:http://172.16.15.11/appointment/src/test1.php');
```

But does not work when i check this file :

```
var_dump(file_exists('http://172.16.15.11/appointment/src/test1.php')); //return false
```

Note - I do not have any .htaccess file

Comment: `http://172.16.15.11/appointment/src/test1.php` isn't a path, it is a URL.

Comment: also var_dump(file_exists('appointment/src/test1.php')); does not work  but var_dump(file_exists('/var/www/html/appointment/src/test1.php')); works

Answer (score 3):

`file_exists()` MAY work for some URLs, but isn't guaranteed, from the manual page...

> Tip As of PHP 5.0.0, this function can also be used with some URL
>   wrappers. Refer to Supported Protocols and Wrappers to determine which
>   wrappers support stat() family of functionality.

You can try...

```
$file = 'http://www.examle.com/somefile.jpg';
$file_headers = @get_headers($file);
if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
    $exists = false;
}
else {
    $exists = true;
}
```

( from http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php#75064 )

`include()` also supports file wrappers (from manual)...

> If "URL
>   include wrappers" are enabled in PHP, you can specify the file to be
>   included using a URL (via HTTP or other supported wrapper - see
>   Supported Protocols and Wrappers for a list of protocols) instead of a
>   local pathname.

BUT as a rule, I wouldn't include anything from a URL.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `file_exists` works with filesystem directory path, and not with URL.

if you want to check with the absolute path you can find it using `getcwd()`

```
file_exists (getcwd() . "/test1.php");
```

Comment: I have tried  var_dump(file_exists('appointment/src/test1.php')); but its not working... its work only when var_dump(file_exists('test1.php'));

Comment: because appointment is not in your root filesystem structure. You can print your current directory using getcwd().

Comment: really thanks after using getcwd() returns /var/www/html/appointment/src 
 var_dump(file_exists('/var/www/html/appointment/src/test1.ph‌​p')); it works.... but var_dump(file_exists('appointment/src/test1.php')); does not work what is the reason

Comment: because not find that file in the relative path you give to the function.
file_exists('appointment/src/test1.php') is the same to write file_exists('/var/www/html/appointment/src/appointment/src/test1.php') and in the path /var/www/html/appointment/src/appointment/src/test1.php there isn't any file...

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget about 301 and etc... Correct only 200...
And check isset always if u don't want have Notice in error log.

```
$headers = @get_headers('http://www.examle.com/somefile.jpg');
if(isset($headers[0]) AND $headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK') {
    $exists = true;
}
else {
    $exists = false;
}
```